# How to search and filter for a text in a fragment

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments

I am able to show the search bar but not able to search for anything, when I type anything inside the search bar and press enter it doesn't filter or come up with results everything just stays as it is, please tell me what's wrong with my code and why it is not coming up with any results, thanks in advance.

```
public class MyJobsFragment extends Fragment {

    MyJobsAdapter adapter;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;


public MyJobsFragment() {

}

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_my_jobs, container, 
    false);

    ArrayList<MyJobsModel> data = new ArrayList<>();
    data.add(new MyJobsModel("Android Developer", "Vee Live", ""));
    data.add(new MyJobsModel("Android Developer", "Vee Live", ""));
    data.add(new MyJobsModel("Android Developer", "Vee Live", ""));
    data.add(new MyJobsModel("Android Developer", "Vee Live", ""));
    data.add(new MyJobsModel("Android Developer", "Vee Live", ""));
    data.add(new MyJobsModel("Android Developer", "Vee Live", ""));
    data.add(new MyJobsModel("Android Developer", "Vee Live", ""));

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
    adapter = new MyJobsAdapter(data, getContext());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));

    RecyclerView.ItemAnimator itemAnimator = new DefaultItemAnimator();
    itemAnimator.setAddDuration(1000);
    itemAnimator.setRemoveDuration(1000);
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(itemAnimator);

    return view;
}


@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.search_view, menu);
    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.menuSearch);
    final SearchView searchView = new SearchView(((Jobs) 
    getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().getThemedContext());
    MenuItemCompat.setShowAsAction(item, 
    MenuItemCompat.SHOW_AS_ACTION_COLLAPSE_ACTION_VIEW | 
    MenuItemCompat.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM);
    MenuItemCompat.setActionView(item, searchView);

    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: There is a good example at the end of [this page](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html). Of course you need to change it a little bit depending on what you want to achieve but at least it's a start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not Filtering the recyclerview's data on `onQueryTextSubmit`

You need to filter the ArrayList and refresh the recyclerview's data once a text is submitted.

```
  searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            ArrayList<MyJobsModel> filteredData = new ArrayList<MyJobsModel>();

            for (MyJobsModel myJobsModel : data) {
                if (myJobsModel.getName().equals(query)) {

                    filteredData.add(myJobsModel);

                }

            }

  adapter = new MyJobsAdapter(data, getContext());
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
            return true ;


        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Your code already explained it all. Thanks again